# Can we create Amazon Lex Chatbot in both mobile and web using iFrame/WebView?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

This is a very generic question I stumbled upon. Can I use Amazon Lex Chatbot and make it available as an iframe and WebView for web and mobile applications respectively?

I know we can make use of AWS Amplify for web and SDK for mobile. But, can we use iframe related approach for both web and mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

However, to answer in a longer form - it actually doesn't matter to Lex where or how you're choosing to interface with the end user.
So long as you're sending Lex the input it requires in the formats it accepts it will work just fine.

How you present the UI to the end user is up to you.